# Does every Form in c#.net needs a new connection to be established with sql database?

Tags: sql, winforms, roles

I am creating a c#.net winforms application which uses sql server2005 express. I have three forms in the application.

So, first i connected to the database with windows authentication when Form1 is displayed which is the main form.It uses the connection string from app.config file.

Then i changed to the application role by executing sp_setapprole on a button click on form1.

Then, Form2 opens and i want that it uses the same application role which was set in form1 to connect to the database.

How do i do it?
Does every Form needs a new connection to be established with sql database?

I have created the application role beforehand in SQL Server.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, I'd say that in general, for a thick (single-threaded) client, you probably want only one connection open (probably for the lifetime of the client).

You can keep the parameterless constructor for Form2 (which will be needed for the VS designer to continue to work), but you can create a second constructor for Form2 that is passed the open connection and continues to work with it, e.g.:

```
public Form2()
{
    InitializeComponent();
}
private SqlConnection _conn;
public Form2(SqlConnection conn)
    : this()
{
    _conn = conn;
}
```

Otherwise (if you're a multi-threaded application), I'd recommend that you only open connections when required, perform your work, then close the connection again. Connection pooling will ensure this isn't as inefficient as it sounds, and trying to share a single connection among multiple threads can get very messy. If you're doing this, you might want to create an extension method on SqlConnection, something like `OpenAndSetAppRole` that will open a new connection and call the sp_setapprole proc before returning

Comment: @Damien_The_Unbeliever, thanx a lot sir, but how do i use it. its giving error. _conn not found . can you give me the full code

Comment: having a connection open for the entire lifecycle of the application is *exactly* what we should not do.

Comment: @sqlchild - did you add the line above the second constructor, that defines the `_conn` private member? I've also assumed that you either have a `using System.Data.SqlClient` statement at the top of Form2, or you'll be prompted to add one. To add more to the above, I'd have to know how you're trying to use the connection in Form2.

Comment: @Felice - it's better than one connection per form that's potentially going to be alive for the lifetime of the app. Besides, if connection pooling is enabled, and the app is reasonably data intensive, the connection is actually going to remain open for the life of the app anyway. By keeping this explicit, you're saving multiple `sp_reset_connection` and `sp_setapprole` calls.

Comment: @Felice, so what's the replacement of this ,sir

Comment: @Felice : shall  i open new connection whenever a new form is opened. and i want that the new form uses the application role set by the old form. how do i do it

Comment: @Felice : ok , so according to you its better to open new connection with new Forms. ok i'll do that.

Comment: @Felice : then , will again i have to set the application role in the new Form. or would i be able to do, that Form2 uses same the application role which was set in Form1

Comment: @Damien_The_Unbeliever, sir, i passed the conn object created in Form1 to the constructor of Form 2 as :                             IN FORM1.CS  -- Form2 f2 = new Form2(conn);
                f2.Show();
IN FORM2.CS --public Form2(SqlConnection conn)
    : this()
{
    _conn = conn;
}                                                                                                         USING THIS, I DID NOT NEED TO DECLARE THE _conn object. it is working. but how do i verify that Form2 is using the application role which was set in Form1. please help

Answer (score 1):

As a starting point have a look at this article:
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms971481.aspx
is a collection of best practices in using ADO.NET. An extract about connection is:

***Using Connections**
High performance applications keep connections to the data source in use for a minimal amount of time, as well as take advantage of performance enhancing technology such as connection pooling. The following topics provide you with tips to help you achieve greater performance when using ADO.NET to connect to your data source.*

In other word you should connect to the database when you are issuing a conversation ( filling a page in a grid, updating a record and so on ).

Comment: sir, how do i verify that my Form2 is using the application role which was set in Form1. also, do i have to make a new connection to the database also, in form2 if i want form2 to use the application role set in form1. i am creating a new database using form2 by clicking a button on form2.

Comment: sir, you can repeat the call at each transaction.

Comment: i din't understood what you mean to say